# How do I align text with a form?

Tags: html, css

I have built a standard footer, emulating the tourlife.com footer. However my link next to the instagram image isn't centered with the image, also the links "terms" and "help" are also out of alignment with the form. This is my second attempt using w3school's 'css grid of boxes/ equal width boxes'.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <footer class="clearfix">
        <div class="box">
            <img class="ig_logo" src="images/instagramicon.jpg">
            <a href="#">@TOURLIFE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <a class="biggertext" href="#">TERMS</a>
            <a class="biggertext" href="#">HELP</a>
            <form class="form">
                <input class="enter" type="email" placeholder="email">
                <button type="submit" class="button_1">SUBSCRIBE</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <p>&copy Copyright Ben Cotta 2020</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Main Footer */

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

.clearfix::after {
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}

.box .biggertext {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0px 4px;
    margin-left: 6px;
}

.box a:visited {
    color: black;
}

.ig_logo {
    height: 100%;
    width: 20px;
}

/* Middle Box */

.form {
    float: right;
}

.enter {
    width: 10vw;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 6px 10px;
}

.button_1 {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    width: 8vw;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Right Box */
```

Answer (score 0):

This is way easier to do with flexbox.

When you set your box width to 33.33% it doesn't know what to refer to. If you set the height of your body it will automatically give 100% width of your screen and the child to your body has a reference.

By typing "display: flexbox" your items under that class will align in a row. Voila!
By using "justify-content", you can decide how you want to spread your items and with "align-items" you can center your items vertically. You must give them space to do this though.

Your Instagram-pic didn't work, so I added a new link. I think it should work.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Main Footer */
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.clearfix {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-right: 10px;
  color: #000;
}
.button_1 {
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

.enter {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <footer class="clearfix">
      <div class="box">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/fluent/48/000000/instagram-new.png" />
        <a href="#">@TOURLIFE</a>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <a class="biggertext" href="#">TERMS</a>
        <a class="biggertext" href="#">HELP</a>
        <form class="form">
          <input class="enter" type="email" placeholder="email" />
          <button type="submit" class="button_1">SUBSCRIBE</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <p>&copy Copyright Ben Cotta 2020</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/battleaxe/5rc9asn0/

Comment: Works wonders mate thank you.. however the elements under the border-line are all left-aligned leaving space on the right;

Comment: Glad it worked. If you put the rest of your stuff in a new div, make sure to use display: flex; justify-content: center. That will center all your stuff within that div.